# Akka TestProbe to test context.watch() / Terminated handling

Tags: akka

I'm testing an akka system using TestKit . One actor of the system I'm testing, upon receiving a certain message type, `context.watch`es the sender, and kills itself when the sender dies:

```
trait Handler extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case Init => context.watch(sender)
        case Terminated => context.stop(self)
    }
}
```

In my test I'm sending

```
val probe = TestProbe(system)
val target = TestActorRef(Props(classOf[Handler]))
probe.send(target, Init)
```

Now, to test the watch / Terminated behavior - I want to simulate the testprobe being killed.

I can do

```
probe.send(target, Terminated)
```

But, this presupposes that target has called `context.watch(sender)` , else it would not receive a Terminated.

I can do

```
probe.testActor ! Kill
```

with doesn't send `Terminated` unless target has correctly called `context.watch(sender)` , but I don't actually want the testprobe killed, as it needs to remain responsive to test if (for example) target continues to send messages instead of stopping itself .

I'm come across this a few times now, what's the correct way to test if an actor is handling the above situation correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could watch the actor under test for termination with a separate probe instead of trying to do that via the 'sender' probe:

```
val probe = TestProbe(system)
val deathWatcher = TestProbe(system)

val target = TestActorRef(Props(classOf[Handler]))
deathWatcher.watch(target)

probe.send(target, Init)
// TODO make sure the message is processed.. perhaps ack it?

probe ! Kill

deathWatcher.expectTerminated(target)
```

Comment: I was having the same issue but with Akka.Net in C#. This approach has also solved my problem.