# How to stop TestProbe in Akka.Net

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

I need to test that my actor properly react on `Terminated` message, and I use `TestProbe` to mock it's children. But for some reason I can't stop `TestProbe` actors. Here is the test:

```cs
    [Test]
    public void TestProbeStopTest()
    {
        var probe = CreateTestProbe("Test");
        Watch(probe);
        Sys.Stop(probe);
        ExpectTerminated(probe);
    }
```

And here is a result:

```
Failed: Timeout 00:00:03 while waiting for a message of type Akka.Actor.Terminated Terminated Akka.TestKit.TestProbe. 
   at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message, Object[] args)
   at Akka.TestKit.TestKitBase.InternalExpectMsgEnvelope[T](Nullable`1 timeout, Action`2 assert, String hint, Boolean shouldLog)
   at Akka.TestKit.TestKitBase.InternalExpectMsgEnvelope[T](Nullable`1 timeout, Action`1 msgAssert, Action`1 senderAssert, String hint)
   at Akka.TestKit.TestKitBase.InternalExpectMsg[T](Nullable`1 timeout, Action`1 msgAssert, String hint)
   at Akka.TestKit.TestKitBase.ExpectTerminated(IActorRef target, Nullable`1 timeout, String hint)
   at Actors.Tests.Common.RootActorTests.TestProbeStopTest()
```

Comment: Please provide the method `CreateTestProbe`

Comment: @Phate01, it is part of [Akka.TestKit](https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-akkadotnet-actors-akka-testkit/) framework =(

Comment: My mistake :D Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946826/akka-testprobe-to-test-context-watch-terminated-handling

Comment: Have you tried `Sys.Stop(probe.Ref)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Horusiath, this code works

```cs
[Test]
public void TestProbeStopTest()
{
    var probe = CreateTestProbe("Test");
    Watch(probe.Ref);
    Sys.Stop(probe.Ref);
    ExpectTerminated(probe.Ref);
}
```